# How do I make the trapezoidal shadow on a rectangle as shown in the image?

Tags: html, css

Here is my html and css. I am able to stack one div onto another in order to create something like given in the image.I am struggling to add a trapezoidal shadow(3-d) as shown in the image.

[image: 1]

```css
.another {
  background-color: #9D8F7E;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  margin: 50px 0px -48px 0px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px ridge black;
}
```

```html
<div class="another"></div>
```

Comment: I think you need another div... That's not really a shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clip-path` can do this:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px;

  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  border-left: var(--s) solid;
  border-right:var(--s) solid;
  
  clip-path:polygon(
      0 var(--s)                 ,var(--s) 0, 
      calc(100% - var(--s)) 0   ,100% var(--s),
      100% calc(100% - var(--s)),calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%,
      var(--s) 100%             ,0 calc(100% - var(--s)))
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

to make a shadow effect you can try pseudo element with some filter:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  margin:0 30px;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:1px;
  bottom:1px;
  width:30px;
  filter:blur(3px);
  background:#000;
}
.box:before {
  right:100%;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(-35deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
.box:after {
  left:100%;
  transform:perspective(100px) rotateY(35deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helped. This is exactly what I needed.